# Mock a server to service a grpc call in python

Tags: python, mocking, grpc

I have an actor that uses the stub with a host and port to request a service from the server. I don't want to change the actor code. Is there a way where I use an instance of the Actor that takes the host and port and calls a service from a mock server? I don't want to create a server I just want to test my client. I looked at grpc_testing, but the documentation didn't really help me and I didn't find any examples. Pytest also doesn't seem to work for this, afaik. I'm a beginner regarding grpc. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately gRPC Python don't provide the ability to create mock server, If you just want to test client side code, the closet thing to do is bring up a very simple (like helloworld) local server as a 'mock'.